# How to catch the IOException "Connection reset by peer"?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp

Parsing the string message seems bad. Or was this exception not meant to be caught?

```
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:21)
```

Comment: More details either stacktrace or code please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to catch the `IOException` and, yes, parse the string.

There isn't any other exception more specific than that to be caught as far as I know.

Or catch `SocketException` and, again, parse the string.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/package-tree.html)'s the class tree from javadoc (version 6). As you can see, `SocketException` is the most specialized exception to be thrown when the connection is reset.

Comment: It isn't a SocketException, it's an IOException. Catching SocketException will therefore not work. Your final sentence is competely incorrct if not nonsensical.

Comment: `Thrown to indicate that there is an error in the underlying protocol, such as a TCP error.`(SocketException description in javadoc) Connection reset is a TCP error (Error code 10054).

Comment: Irrelevant. When you get an exception with the text "connection reset" it is an `IOException`, not a `SocketException`. Try it. You can't just infer it from the Javadoc class hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

The JVM makes no difference about the real cause of the error, hence it will throw a *generic* `IOException` in any case (adapter disconnected, timeout, ICMP error...). Only the human readable string describes the error and there is nothing you can do about it.